# Log viewer issue after upgrading to 5.57.1

Tags: permissions, logs, logging, configandlog

I just updated some CiviCRM staging/test sites to 5.57.1 and my log viewer seems to be broken. This is Drupal 7 site

I get something like the following error for all sites:

```
Unable to read entries from logfile at /var/www/html/mysite/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1_3d2d307c1a3c8afb45487079.log
```

If I look in the directory `ConfigAndLog` I can see the file permissions are `644` owner is `www-data`. The Directory is `664` with `www-data` as owner.

The log file listed above is not there though, instead I find two active log files:

```
CiviCRM.1_2f42dac95054c9bfcda8461a.log
CiviCRM.389f69036b9921e16e572d2f.log
```

One appears to be the summary and one the stacktrace.

They are an hour or so old. Their last entries are messages confirming a successful upgrade to 5.57.1... yay.

I have cleared every imaginable cache many times. What is going on here? Is log creation failing? I had to update my SITE_KEY configuration on this upgrade, could that have broken it? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is a bit misleading and usually just means "you have no new messages yet" and I think that's what it means this time. There was a recent change in core to prefix log file names with the domain id, so that's where the `1_` is coming from. The hash is different from the earlier one because you said you cleared cache which will change that hash.

If you want to double-check, just add `\Civi::log()->info('hi');` in any civi form file, then visit that page, then check the log. For example, just after [line 240](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0a41fd5d1a981ddd55a0fad01c130f99c12623bf/CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php#L240) in CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php add `\Civi::log()->info('hi');` (in 5.57.1 it's line 233 but doesn't matter - just somewhere in that function), and then visit Contacts -> New Activity. Then check the log. It should say "hi" in the log.